# Convert two orthogonal unit vectors into euler vector

Tags: vectors, rotations

I have two orthogonal unit vectors that would correspond to an orientation of the Z and Y axes. I want to convert this to a rotation/Euler vector.

In other words, I want to convert between two orthogonal unit vectors into an [Euler vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Euler_axis_and_angle_.28rotation_vector.29).

Answer (score 0):

I think I could use the cross product to get the third axis. These three unit vectors then form a basis and can form a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix) where each vector forms a column of the matrix.

Then one can [use a formula to convert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix_.E2.86.94_Euler_axis.2Fangle) from the rotation matrix to the euler vector.